# How to calculate the longest period in days that the company has gone without hiring anyone

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following table, I would like to calculate the longest period in days that the company has gone without hiring anyone.

[image: Image of table]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT EmpID, MAX(Hire_Date-e.Hire_Date) AS maxDiff 
FROM employees
    LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.EmpID = employees.EmpID 
        AND employees.Hire_Date >= e.Hire_Date
WHERE e.Hire_Date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY EmpID;
```

Comment: the longest period between two dates within the table or compared to the current day (today)

Comment: longer period between two dates within the table - thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't use an image for data, even a table. Copy and paste in data into your question so it can be copied out and reused to generate a simple table, or better, create a small snippet of insert statements that'll create the table and paste that into the question, formatted appropriately. Doing so helps us help you. See "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)"

Comment: Why didn't your code work? Please see "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select datediff(next_hd, hiredate) as days_since_prev_hire
from (select t.*,
             lead(hiredate) over (order by hiredate) as next_hd
      from t
     ) t
where next_hd is not null
order by datediff(next_hd, hiredate) desc;
```

Note that this does not include the final, most recent hire.  For that, remove the `where` clause and use:

```
order by datediff(coalesce(next_hd, curdate()), hiredate) desc
```

Comment: with "most recent hire" you mean a date that is not included in the table above?

Comment: @Johnsonjohans . . . I mean the time frame between the current date and the most recent hire.

Answer (score 0):

Using ANSI SQL and converting the strings to dates:

```
SELECT
  empid,
  STR_TO_DATE(hire_date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS hire_date,
  DATEDIFF(
    STR_TO_DATE(hire_date,'%d/%m/%Y'),
    (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(hire_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) FROM hiring WHERE STR_TO_DATE(hire_date,'%d/%m/%Y') < STR_TO_DATE(t.hire_date,'%d/%m/%Y'))
  ) AS days_since_last_hiring
FROM hiring AS t ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(hire_date,'%d/%m/%Y');
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------+------------------------+
| empID | hire_date  | days_since_last_hiring |
+-------+------------+------------------------+
|   103 | 2015-02-03 |                   NULL |
|   407 | 2016-01-07 |                    338 |
|   333 | 2016-08-07 |                    213 |
|   409 | 2016-10-15 |                     69 |
|   410 | 2017-01-01 |                     78 |
|   413 | 2017-01-01 |                     78 |
+-------+------------+------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Of course last two rows have one and the same diffs as they are compared with the previous row with lower date